# Rotate Cube around center on button click

Tags: javascript, three.js

Imagine a cube-like object: [image]

This is placed on face 6 on a vertical plane. 
I want this cube to change its position with a button click. 
So I click the button --> Now face 5 is on the plane. Button again --> 3 is on the plane. 
The order resulting out of this should be: 6 5 3 2 1 4 --> 6 5 . . .

I tried it with s.th. like this: (sideCounter is the number of clicks)

```
    if (this._sideCounter === 0) {
      this._arModelObject.matrix = matrix.compose(translation, rotation.clone().multiply(new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler().setFromVector3(new THREE.Vector3(-(Math.PI / 2), 0, 0)))), scale);
    }
    if (this._sideCounter === 1 || this._sideCounter === 2) {
      this._arModelObject.matrix = matrix.compose(translation, rotation.clone().multiply(new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler().setFromVector3(new THREE.Vector3(0, -(Math.PI / 2), 0)))), scale);
    }
    if (this._sideCounter === 3) {
      this._arModelObject.matrix = matrix.compose(translation, rotation.clone().multiply(new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler().setFromVector3(new THREE.Vector3(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0)))), scale);
    }
    if (this._sideCounter === 4 || this._sideCounter === 5) {
      this._arModelObject.matrix = matrix.compose(translation, rotation.clone().multiply(new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler().setFromVector3(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -(Math.PI / 2))))), scale);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

A solution for the rotation problem so far was provided (thx @Eponyme Web). Problem here is, that I don't rotate around the center right now. (The cubes origin (0,0,0) is somewhere else (because it depends on the uploaded model of the user))

Is there an easy way to center the rotation (**just for the roation!!**)?

Comment: It looks to me like you only have two types of transformation based on sideCounter: 1 and 2 go into the screen, 3 and 4 go left, 5 go into the screen and 6 goes left. Wouldn't it be easier to use that information and start form the current state each time instead of the original state?

Comment: Your code could be simpler by modifying rotation vector instead of modifying matrix...

Comment: @PalleDue do you have a suggestion how? (I also updated the above code... made a mistake copying)

Comment: @breezertwo: No, I'm afraid my 2 cents are already spent.

Comment: You'd need to move the cube (or the origin) at the beginning so the rotation behave as expected. I'd move the bottom front left corner to the origin then move in each axis by 1/2 the length of the cube so it would be centered.

Answer (score 1):

I think the transformation for count 0 and 3 is identical

```
if (this._sideCounter === 0 || this._sideCounter === 3) {
  this._arModelObject.matrix = matrix.compose(translation, rotation.clone().multiply(new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler().setFromVector3(new THREE.Vector3(-(Math.PI / 2), 0, 0)))), scale);
}
if (this._sideCounter === 1 || this._sideCounter === 2) {
  this._arModelObject.matrix = matrix.compose(translation, rotation.clone().multiply(new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler().setFromVector3(new THREE.Vector3(0, -(Math.PI / 2), 0)))), scale);
}
if (this._sideCounter === 4 || this._sideCounter === 5) {
  this._arModelObject.matrix = matrix.compose(translation, rotation.clone().multiply(new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler().setFromVector3(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -(Math.PI / 2))))), scale);
}
```

Comment: no this is wrong. if i do on 3 the same as 0 not the top (1) will be on the plane, instead It is the bottom again (6)

Comment: @breezertwo I'd be happy to look again but with the rest of the code I could actually run it and that would remove the guessing.

Comment: During trying to provide a fiddle for you I found out that your solution works in general. I have the problem that the center of my object is not the rotation point right now... I'll edit the question! Thanks so far

Comment: @breezertwo I'm looking forward to the next one then :) a fiddle would help.